# Can I get the events directly from an HScrollBar in .net?

Tags: .net, scrollbar

I have an odd requirement. Our data has ticks, which are time-related. Each tick may have from 0 to 50 data points in them. I want the ticks laid out on the scrollbar, so if you drag the handle, you scroll through ticks. But I want the arrows to change between data points, so that if you use one of the arrows to step through, you'll see every data point.

Is it possible for me to get the events directly from the HScrollBar so I know whether the user clicked an arrow or dragged the handle?

Comment: I think the TrackBar was meant for that.

Comment: Hmm... The TrackBar only has the slider. I need both the slider and arrows. Unless there's something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use `HScrollBar` and `VScrollBar` directly, although it doesn't give you the positions in the way you say you want them. You can set the amount of space it moves when the user clicks an arrow (that would be the `SmallIncrement` and `SmallDecrement`) and when the user clicks in the scroller area (`LargeIncrement` and `LargeDecrement`). But you can't set the amount of space it moves when the user is dragging the thumb.

You could potentially move the scroller position when the user stops dragging (by rounding the resulting position), but that might confuse the user. Look into the `HScrollBar.Scroll` event and the `ScrollEventArgs.Type` property.

It's probably better to use the `TrackBar` and add left and right arrow buttons to your UI. Making a `HScrollBar` work the way you want is going to be difficult, and it probably wouldn't look as nice as the `TrackBar`.

Answer (score 1):

The ScrollBar is not meant for that.  For one thing, the range is based on the Minimum to Maximum and then offset by the LargeChange value.  In other words, the ScrollBar does not scroll through from Minimum to Maximum (like it use to do in VB6).

Try using the TrackBar control instead.  You don't get arrows, just a handle, but it gives you almost everything you are looking for.

Comment: With TrackBar how do I differentiate between going from tick to tick and going from data point to data point? I'm not saying you're wrong, I just don't quite understand how to get it to behave in these two ways.

Comment: @Almo Not sure I understand your ticks to data points description.  Picture might make that clear.  It sounds like you want to treat the arrows and handle as separate things, almost completely unrelated.

Comment: We have varying amounts of data for each time bin. For example, we might get 1 data point in the first second, 20 in the second second, and 2 in the third second. I want the scroll bar to have 3 locations for the handle: 1st, 2nd and 3rd second. But if I put it on the 2nd, I want to have to click the right arrow 20 times to step through the 20 data points there before the handle moves over to the 3rd second.

Comment: @Almo Sounds like a UserControl with buttons on the ends and the TrackBar filling the middle.  What you are describing isn't going to happen with the ScrollBar, because the arrows and the handle are both reporting the "value" of the control-- you can't separate that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wish I could accept multiple answers, but I can at least upvote both.